# jQuery panaroma viewer plugin Not Work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I work With jQuery [panaroma viewer](https://github.com/peachananr/panorama_viewer) Plugin. But Not work in action.

HTML:

```
<div class="panorama">
    <img src="http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/panorama_viewer/demo_photo.jpg">
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".panorama").panorama_viewer({
    repeat: false, 
    direction: "horizontal", 
    animationTime: 700, 
    easing: "ease-out",
    overlay: true 
});
```

How Do can I fix This?

[DEMO JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5MGeh/)

Answer (score 0):

Under "Frameworks & Extensions" change onLoad to onDomready. :) Works fine.

You'll need to wrap your initialisation code like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".panorama").panorama_viewer({
    repeat: false, 
    direction: "horizontal", 
    animationTime: 700, 
    easing: "ease-out",
    overlay: true 
  });
});
```

HTML File:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="link-to-jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="link-to-panorama.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".panorama").panorama_viewer({
    repeat: false, 
    direction: "horizontal", 
    animationTime: 700, 
    easing: "ease-out",
    overlay: true 
  });
});

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="panorama">
        <img src="http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/panorama_viewer/demo_photo.jpg">
    </div>
...
```

Comment: Then your HTML may be in the wrong order.
Make sure you import JQuery, then the plugin, and then call this function.

Can you post it here?